# Bubbling object or properties?

Tags: actionscript-3, events, event-bubbling

I have a bubbled event that activates an event in the root class. From the root class I add an object that wants to use the properties of the object that activated the bubbled event. I do this with this code:

```
public function addInfoWindow(e:Event):void
{
    dockTarget = e.target as DisplayObject;
    infoWindow = new InfoWindow();
    addChild(infoWindow);
    infoWindow.setContent(dockTarget.x, dockTarget.y, dockTarget._id, dockTarget._name, dockTarget._description);
}
```

The x and y values get passed fine, but with the properties _id, _name and _description I get an "Access of possibly undefined property _id through a reference with static type DisplayObject." error.

I'm assuming that when I passed the event target as a displayObject the target object became static.

So is there another way to bubble the object or its properties? Or is there some other way to achieve this effect?

Comment: You might want to check if the dockTarget is the object you are expecting. Also, where do you add your eventlistener to? If it's the dockTarget, maybe you want to use e.currentTarget?

Comment: You might want to check if dockTarget has the propertys _id etc. with dockTarget.hasOwnProperty('_id')

Comment: It's getting the right object and it has the property _id. I have finally solved it though. Instead of using displayObject, I used object.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the e.target as DisplayObject, pass it as an Object.

```
public function addInfoWindow(e:Event):void
{
    dockTarget = e.target as Object;
    infoWindow = new InfoWindow();
    addChild(infoWindow);
    infoWindow.setContent(dockTarget.x, dockTarget.y, dockTarget._id, dockTarget._name, dockTarget._description);
}
```

Comment: While casting to `Object` does work, as will casting to `MovieClip` if that `e.target` is one, generally it'll be better to first query its type via `if (e.target is OneClass) {...}` so that you can reach properties of `OneClass` class, etc. This works especially good if you are extending something other than `MovieClip`, for example, if you don't need to use local timeline.